# Why can't I post my question on Super User?

Tags: discussion, support, question-quality

Well, I've been using the Stack Exchange sites since a while, and, I could say that, I'm not a total newbie on these sites. But, there's something so annoying that I couldn't able to send and ask any question sometimes.

I'm trying to post this question:

> Does Facebook work with Latex, could you give me some information about this? And, if it's possible, what should I do to use Latex on Facebook? Thank you for the reading... :)

Here's the exact message:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because: It does not meet our quality standards.

So how can I start enjoying the site like other users instead of getting that message?

Comment: Have you checked the other question-quality tagged questions here and made sure they don't apply to you?

Comment: What's the full text of the question you were trying to post?

Comment: Here, which I'd like to send, ask and learn about it:

"Does Facebook work with Latex, could you give me some information about this?

And, if it's possible, what should I do to use Latex on Facebook?

Thank you for the reading... :)"

So, what's the problem with this kind of postings? Which word is black-listed for example?? Thank you for your attention by the way.

Comment: @DanielBeck: For the "Super User" section, I didn't check and read the "question-quality" tagged ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Taken from your comment, the text of the question you wish to post is:

> Does Facebook work with Latex, could you give me some information about this? And, if it's possible, what should I do to use Latex on Facebook? Thank you for the reading... :)

First, as an aside, this is actually **off-topic**. Facebook is a WebApp and so it's off topic on Super User (see the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq)). [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) *might* be able to help, if you improve the question first.

As for the problem with this question, it's **too short**.

It's no secret that the quality filter hates short questions (with good reason, they're rarely useful - usually degrading into comment streams of people asking follow up questions, or just as likely a non-question) so I highly suspect that's why it was rejected in this case.

Comment: Well, but, how about the "Facebook" tag on the "Super User", I'd checked it already, sir...? And, don't you think that, sometimes people ask something which might be seem or sound "very simple" for some of us, so, couldn't they deserve to ask and learn about those subjects, sir...? Isn't there any more useful or alternative sanitizing approchings for these...? Thank you very much for your all help and advices by the way.

Comment: @KerimAtasoy The development team created the quality filters using years of test data (from questions on the network) and very short questions were found to be much more likely to be poor quality. I can't comment any more than that as they keep the exact details secret, even from us community mods. As for the facebook tag, you can't see the 473 that are deleted (compared to 71 live, 9 of which are closed waiting deletion)... and could ask about (for eg) why your browser can't load facebook, but asking about how Facebook itself works (such as if it supports LaTeX) is off-topic here.

Comment: OK, "DMA", I got my answer for now... :) Thank you, sincerely. :)